# Multiple domains, one IP, multiple servers

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, ip, reverse-proxy, windows-server-2012

Alright, here is the thing...

I have several devices/computers/servers on my network which provides services such as web pages (both through *Apache* and *IIS*), *RDP*, *Subversion*, *DVBLink* etc. Two of these are *Synology* boxes, one is a *Mac Mini* running a dual boot with *Windows Server 2012* and *Mac OS*, and one is a *Windows 7* installation. So there are several platforms involved.

Currently, only one domain points to my network, however, I have other domains I can use. In the past when I want to request pages from different web servers on the network, I have requested on different ports such as 81, 8080 etc., however this is not how I would like to do it, since these URLs are not particular usefull publicly. I have managed to set a proxy/reverse proxy up on one of the *Apache* servers redirecting the different requests e.g. using subdomains to other physical servers, however, this is only for serving http content and done with mod_proxy etc. This does not work perfectly since I need to rewrite the *HTML* due to wrong references in the *HTML*.

What I really would like is to serve all different kinds of services on the network forwarded to different servers using domain names or subdomains. Most important are *HTTP* and *RDP*, and I guess, if done the right way it does not matter what is served. In short, I want it to be transparent that I only have one external IP to access my network, and still be able to serve content from all boxes on the network to the outside.

*Can this be accomplished?*

The plan was to try using the *Windows Server 2012* runnning on the *Mac Mini* to do this using *DNS*, but this is where I get into trouble. I am not completely sure what I do at this stage. I have tried to set up a conditional forwards in the *DNS Manager* where I map from the domain to an internal IP. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. I tried to turn on the *Default DMZ* in the router since I was told that this might strip the domain name from the packets. I was not able to make this work either.

*Can it be accomplished and am I on the right track?*

I will be really grateful if you could point me in the right direction, and if you have some good and useful resources on how to configure the *Windows Server* to accomplish this, if possible.

Comment: I suppose it might be possible to be done with some weird clustering thing but I don't know of any ways that work cross-platform. It might be easier to look at putting all sites on one machine.

Comment: Are you doing this in a workplace setting or in a home setting ? What's your budget ?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your responses. Expected something like "you just have to do it this way..." :o) Well, it is only in a home setting, with a little twist that I also have a small company to which one of the Synology servers belong. I am quite interested in hosting these things myself, thus getting experience related to these network settings. Tom, thanks, but it is not only web pages, and I have Wordpress on one box in a multisite setup, and PhotoStation on both boxes etc., and would like to have RDP to both Windows machines. Thanks, Jacob.

Comment: This is one of the problems that NAT causes. Be sure to get yourself some IPv6, which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP, you may be able to use mod_proxy or mod_rewrite to redirect based on the incoming URL. If that doesn't work, and for RDP, you're pretty much stuck using different ports on the incoming IP to redirect to the appropriate port on the real host. Other protocols may offer other options, but with RDP you're kinda stuck.